# default border color for .net textbox

Tags: asp.net

I change the border style and border color on a .net textbox to solid red respectively.  After a postback I am attempting to return the textbox to its default values, but I cannot seem to get the color right.  I have googled this, and tried to get the default values in the debugger, but the values in the debugger always look too dark of a gray when applied.  Is there an easy way to return to the default look and feel of a textbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write two CSS classes:

```
.tb_with_border {
 border: 1px #FF0000 solid;
}

.tb_without_border {
 border: none;
}
```

.. and then you can change styles by assigning CssClass property of your textbox, for example:

```
Textbox1.CssClass = "tb_without_border";
```

or in markup:

```
<asp:TextBox id="Textbox1" runat="server" CssClass="tb_with_border" />
```

Answer (score 15):

try this:

```
TextBoxTitle.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just switching the particular element style off then this works:

```
Textbox1.BorderColor = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using CSS to do this anyways...

```
Textbox1.Style.Remove("border")
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work - I use Textbox1.Style.Remove("border-color") but the textbox seems to maintain the border-color attribute.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.  I know CSS is the better option and i may have to go that route but since they provide the functionality to change this I thought I would use it for a quick fix. I thought it would be easier to go back to the default values.

Answer (score 0):

```
txt_TextBox.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
txt_TextBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.NotSet;
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple. Add another textbox or dropdownlist with default values and make it hidden.
To RESET to defaults, just set your textbox's border color, width and style to that of the hidden textbox like so:

txtMyTextBoxToReset.BorderColor = txtHiddenTextBox.BorderColor;
txtMyTextBoxToReset.BorderWidth = txtHiddenTextBox.BorderWidth;

This works in all browsers and works for Drop down lists as well